# Change button and div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I need to mimic this websites function with the "view 360" button: http://www.designrattan.co.uk/daybed/apple

I have already got the 360 script worked out it is JUST THE BUTTON that I cannot work out?

I have attempted it here:
http://designliving.tk/winchester-rattan-garden-round-table-set

but several things are wrong as you can see.

I need the DIV to change when clicking the button, but I also need the button to change every time it is clicked (from "view 360" to "view image").

In addition to that I need the images in my photos tab to be able to change the div and button back to "view 360"

I think I have the JavaScript but I dont know how to use this in conjunction with HTML

```
$('.yourButton').bind('click',function(){
if (!$('.yourButton').hasClass('dragMode')) {
    $('.yourButton').addClass('dragMode');
    $('.yourButton').attr('value')="Drag [...]";
} else { // if in drag mode
    $('.yourButton').removeClass('dragMode');
    $('.yourButton').attr('value')="View 360";
}
});

$('.yourTabImages').bind('click',function(){
if ($('.yourButton').hasClass('dragMode')) {
    $('.yourButton').removeClass('dragMode');
    $('.yourButton').attr('value')="View 360";
}
});
```

I hope this all makes sense!,

Thanks everyone!

Comment: please post your relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

If you use jquery, it can be easily achieved with something like :

```
$('.yourButton').bind('click',function(){
    if (!$('.yourButton').hasClass('dragMode')) {
        $('.yourButton').addClass('dragMode');
        $('.yourButton').attr('value')="Drag [...]";
    } else { // if in drag mode
        $('.yourButton').removeClass('dragMode');
        $('.yourButton').attr('value')="View 360";
    }
});

$('.yourTabImages').bind('click',function(){
    if ($('.yourButton').hasClass('dragMode')) {
        $('.yourButton').removeClass('dragMode');
        $('.yourButton').attr('value')="View 360";
    }
});
```

This way you can validate in which mode your button is when choosing which method to call when handling the click event. Hope this helps

Comment: If you look on my website I have already cracked the 360 script! I need to know how to do the button that controls the DIV?

Comment: My post was about the button that controls the div, otherwise I didn't understand what your problem really is. Can you explain what is the expected behavior of this button vs what it is now ?

Comment: Ahh thank-you I didn't realise. Could you ezplain how I would use this in conjunction with html code? Thanks!

Comment: considering that jquery is loaded, binding these 2 events like this should do the job : $(document).ready(function() { //... });

Comment: I still dont understand, I think you are overestimating my knowledge on this! Could you talk to me like a 5 year old lol! I dont know what html I would use in conjunction with this script to make it work with DIVs and buttons

Comment: I'll explain you more in details tomorow or later this week, I don't have too much time right now. until then, here's something you may find useful to read about if you plan to make a lot of interactive html / javascript / css : http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

Dont implement you own code, that will take time. Use this any of plugin which you like:
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/jquery-360-degrees-image-display-plugins/#.T_wDU5GFp9g